# Running react native app in Android Virtual Device on Windows

Tags: android, react-native

I'm near frustration. I'm trying to get my react native app to run for hours. all tutorials I find, are skipping the part of Android Virtual devices not starting properly.

I have my react package via node and expo.

HOME and JAVA variables are set. VT-X is enabled. Android Studio is up to date. Whenever I start the Android Virtual Device (set up as Pixel 2) the Android device keeps presenting the Animated Google Logo, but doesn't start.

When I try to start the Android Device via Expo localhost I get an error about  USB debugging, which I don't want.

> Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: No Android
>   device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here
>   to enable USB debugging:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options.
>   If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom
>   Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Error** occurred because the current `computer` and `emulator` are not connected.

Did you set up the `Genymotion` as described in the error?

If you hadn't, go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools" ->

and point it at your Android SDK directory.

Download the SDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ to `C:\android-sdk\`

```
C:\android-sdk\
```

Run emulator, click  `developer options`, enable `USB debugging` and enable `Wi-Fi to Cellular`.

Run the `Genymotion Shell` and type `devices list` to find the IP address of the device.

Open the terminal and enter `adb connect deviceIp:5555`. Make sure the connection to `adb device` is correct. Enter `adb usb` and `adb tcpip 5555`.

[Android adb documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb?hl=en)